# How to use .htaccess mod_rewrite to make an seo friendly url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make an SEO friendly URL using an .htaccess file.

The url I am trying to change looks like this:

https://www.example.com/category/?title=a+really+really+long+title

and what I would like to have is:

https://www.example.com/category/a+really+really+long+title/

I have tried:

`RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^/category/?title=(.+)$    ^/category/$1/    [NC]`

but it does not give me the desired results. Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^title\=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?category/?$ /category/%1 [NC,R,L,QSD]
```

- We first check to see if there is a query string present using `RewriteCond`. If it matches  `^title\=(.+)$`, meaning, if there is a query string with key `title`, then capture the value of it.
- Using RewriteRule, we match if request URI has a `category`. If yes, then rewrite it as `/category/%1` where `%1` is the value of the `title` key matched in rewrite condition for a query string. The `%1` is a [backreference](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)(scroll down a bit) to the captured group number in the regex(of the query string).
- **Note that** if you want to do it for any key-value pair in the query string, then change `title` to `\w+` or `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` to be more precise.